# GeoServer shows me blank preview layer with Java exceptions

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to run the preview layer in a new GeoServer install on Mac. However, I get the following response from the server:

> HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException:
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
> initialize class sun.java2d.SurfaceData

I have tried to reinstall GeoServer and Java multiple times. Also I have made some research, some have this issue and recommend to remove the JAI files in java/extensions (but I don't have any JAI files in this directory).

I'm running the last version of GeoServer (2.19), under the last MacOS version (11.4), with the last version of Java (build 16.0.1)

Comment: Could you try some older Java? Geoserver is developed and tested to work with Java versions 8 and 11.

Comment: GeoServer only supports Java 8 & 11 - Java 16 is completely untested.

Comment: It works with the JAVA 8, i had to many java version installed on my mac. Thanks guys !